# JPanel inside JScrollPane with graphics glitches while scrolling

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jscrollpane

So i made a simple graphic GUI where the rigth part is a JScrollPane with a JPanel (canvas) inside (mainGUI class). When I try to draw some box (using Box class) and run it, when scrolling i get this repeating windowsXP graphic error, where the boxes kind of render too slow or something, kind of dificult to explain. How can I get an uniform non-glitching drawing after scrolling? Is there a rendering option or something?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Grafin{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        mainGUI gui = new mainGUI();
    }
}

class mainGUI{
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel toolsPanel;
    private JPanel canvasPanel;

    public mainGUI(){
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Grafin | untitled");
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainFrame.setSize(920, 580);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);     

        loadGUI();
    }

    public void loadGUI(){
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //toolsPanel (izq) y canvasPanel (der) dentro de mainFrame
        toolsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        toolsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,580));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainFrame.add(toolsPanel, c);


        canvasPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        canvasPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        canvasPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,1000));

        JScrollPane canvasScroll = new JScrollPane(canvasPanel);
        canvasScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(670,580));

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.9;
        mainFrame.add(canvasScroll, c);
        canvasScroll.setSize(canvasScroll.getPreferredSize());
        canvasScroll.setBackground(Color.white);

        //CanvasPanel:
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;

        Box b1 = new Box(10, 200, 30, 128);
        Box b2 = new Box(200, 10, 120, 40);
        canvasPanel.add(b1, c);
        canvasPanel.add(b2, c);
        mainFrame.pack();
    }
}

    class Box extends JPanel{
    private Color borderColor;
    private Color fillColor;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public Box(){
        borderColor = Color.black;
        fillColor = new Color(242, 242, 242);
        x = y = 1;
        width = height = 30;
    }

    public Box(int px, int py, int w, int h){
        x = px;
        y = py;
        borderColor = Color.black;
        fillColor = new Color(242, 242, 242);
        width = w;
        height = h; 
    }

    public void changeFillColor(Color c){
        fillColor = c;
    }

    public void changeBorderColor(Color c){
        borderColor = c;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(fillColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.setColor(borderColor);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
Happy holidays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, you're overriding the wrong painting method. You should not be overriding JPanel's paint method but rather its paintComponent method, since this is a more specific painting method and has double buffering by default, a plus when doing animation (which you're kind of doing with your scrolling).

Even more important is that you're not calling the super's painting method within your override, `super.paintComponent(g)` if overriding paintComponent, or `super.paint(g)` if (incorrectly) overriding paint. This prevents your JPanel from cleaning dirty pixels.

Other issues: You're adding two components to a GridBagLayout-using component, but are using the very same GridBagConstraints for both, something that you shouldn't be doing.

Also, your Box class should be a *logical* class and not a *component* class. In other words, it shouldn't extend any Swing GUI component, and should be drawn within the canvasPanel.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Grafin2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 920;
    private static final int PREF_H = 580;
    private static final Dimension TOOLS_SIZE = new Dimension(250, PREF_H);
    private static final Dimension CANVAS_SIZE = new Dimension(1500, 1000);
    private JPanel toolsPanel = new JPanel();
    private CanvasPanel canvasPanel = new CanvasPanel();

    public Grafin2() {
        MyBox box1 = new MyBox(10, 200, 30, 128);
        MyBox box2 = new MyBox(200, 10, 120, 40);

        box1.changeFillColor(new Color(255, 120, 120));
        box2.changeFillColor(new Color(220, 220, 255));

        canvasPanel.addMyBox(box1);
        canvasPanel.addMyBox(box2);

        toolsPanel.setPreferredSize(TOOLS_SIZE);
        canvasPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        canvasPanel.setPreferredSize(CANVAS_SIZE);
        JScrollPane canvasScroll = new JScrollPane(canvasPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(toolsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(canvasScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {
        // a collection to hold all the boxes
        private List<MyBox> boxes = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addMyBox(MyBox myBox) {
            boxes.add(myBox);
        }

        @Override // again, this is the proper painting method
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); // never forget this!
            for (MyBox myBox : boxes) {
                myBox.draw(g); // draw all the boxes that we hold
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Grafin2 mainPanel = new Grafin2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grafin2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

// this is a logical class, **not** a component class.
class MyBox {
    private Color borderColor;
    private Color fillColor;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public MyBox() {
        borderColor = Color.black;
        fillColor = new Color(242, 242, 242);
        x = y = 1;
        width = height = 30;
    }

    public MyBox(int px, int py, int w, int h) {
        x = px;
        y = py;
        borderColor = Color.black;
        fillColor = new Color(242, 242, 242);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void changeFillColor(Color c) {
        fillColor = c;
    }

    public void changeBorderColor(Color c) {
        borderColor = c;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // no need to call a super method
        // because there is none for this class
        g.setColor(fillColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.setColor(borderColor);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, have been busy with finals. Thank you very much for your answer, going to try it out and see if it works.

Comment: @Luis_V: thanks for getting back to me, and glad it's working.